# Why do List<T>.Add and List<T>.Remove copy the elements into a new array instead of actually adding and removing?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, list, data-structures

I was looking at [`List<T>`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,cf7f4095e4de7646) in [ReferenceSource](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/) and found that `List<T>.Add` (also `Remove` and `RemoveAt`) actually copies the internal list array (`T[] _items`) into a new array with the new modifications; they actually call `Array.Copy` method, that calls the [CLR-internal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimploptions.aspx) method [`Copy`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,757884fad3fffbe4). I don't know how does that internal method (`Copy`) work, but if it does as what it was called (copying), then I believe this would be a performance-expensive way for adding items to or removing items from a list; and I'm wondering why there's no actual add and remove?

Comment: `Add` will only need to copy the array when resizing which should happen infrequently. If you remove from anywhere but the end of a list you will have to move the elements after the removed item down in the source array, which is what the `Array.Copy` call is doing.

Comment: If you look more closely at that code, I think you will find that it does not expand/copy the array *every time you add or remove.*

Comment: But still at some point, the whole elements will be copied into a new array; and that's what I'm talking about; why there's no actual add and remove.

Comment: Arrays have a fixed size so increasing the size is necessary.  It doubles the array size when necessary, an algorithm that has amortized O(1) complexity.  Can't do better than that.  This is wasteful of address space but not of physical memory thanks to the demand-paged virtual memory operating system your program runs on.  Arrays are otherwise very important to improve locality of reference, a very big deal on modern processors and ensure the processor caches are used most effectively.  If you have a good guess for the final collection size then setting the Capacity is useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Add` method does not always copy the internal array. When the array is filled with items it's items are moved to a new one, twice the size.

As far as `Remove` goes. You can see that it will perform the copy operation only if the `index` is smaller than the `_size`. This means that if you attempt to remove the last element from the list, there is no need for the internal array to resize, it simply removes the last element. However, if you want to remove an element from the middle you need to create "shift" left the elements after the removed index.

This is why if you are to remove many elements from arbitrary indexes in a `List<T>` you another data structure is recommended, such as `LinkedList`.

Comment: *However, if you want to remove an element from the middle you need to create a whole new array which excludes the element you just removed.* That's not true, all it does is to "shift" left the elements after the removed index.

Comment: Thanks, didn't really look into it I guess.

Comment: +1 .. Great clarification, but still at some point, the whole elements will be copied into a new array; and that's what I'm talking about; why there's no actual add and remove.

Comment: @AlyEl-Haddad: The reason all elements are copied is that when the allocated array is full, we need more space for elements. There is no way to add more space to the additional array allocation, so you have to create a new, larger, array. It's just like if you try to add an item to a box that's already full. You can't just make the box bigger. You have to get a larger box and move the entire contents of the original box to the new, larger, box. In short, once an array is allocated, its size can't change.